# Error when publishing wall posts VKontakte, VK-SDK

Tags: java, android, api, vk

I Faced with such a problem ... I do publish on the wall through createWallPost, simple text, plain text of any length from a few characters to a very large text ...Publishes through once. Publish once the next, the same record will give an error. ... I'm confused. Can you please tell me why?

method of publishing of record:

```
api.createWallPost(account.user_id, text, null, null, false, false, false, null, null, new Long(0), new Long(0), null, null);
```

log error:
`06-05 06:33:57.930: I/Kate.Api(14959): code=200
06-05 06:33:57.930: I/Kate.Api(14959): response={"error":{"error_code":100,"error_msg":"One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid:  invalid message param","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"wall.post"},{"key":"access_token","value":"18ef018fcc8966be5c568be9044a5d68d3341e6caedcdd6b4a1e11abe1c1f41e77be8ced4fed1d847a04f"},{"key":"owner_id","value":"203334145"},{"key":"publish_date","value":"0"},{"key":"v","value":"5.5"}]}}
06-05 06:33:57.930: W/System.err(14959): com.perm.kate.api.KException: One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid:  invalid message param
06-05 06:33:57.930: W/System.err(14959):    at com.perm.kate.api.Api.checkError(Api.java:45)
06-05 06:33:57.930: W/System.err(14959):    at com.perm.kate.api.Api.sendRequest(Api.java:101)
06-05 06:33:57.930: W/System.err(14959):    at com.perm.kate.api.Api.createWallPost(Api.java:1203)
06-05 06:33:57.930: W/System.err(14959):    at com.screen.Social_content$5.run(Social_content.java:203)`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make more than three requests per second to vk api. Sometimes even the third request doesn't go through.